# Update query for duplicates

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have small problem with my SQL Update query.

I have this code:

```
UPDATE records
SET kp= -kp
WHERE av=pm
  AND secret_key = 123
  AND date='2014-01-21'
  AND pm IN
    (SELECT pm
     FROM
       (SELECT pm,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY secret_key
                                 ORDER BY secret_key ASC) AS row_num
        FROM records) platnosc
     WHERE platnosc.row_num > 1
       AND secret_key =1
       AND dt_payment_date='2014-01-21');
```

The above code should only work when:

1. I have duplicates (more than 1 record with data with the same parameters date and secret_key)
2. I need update only records when I have more that one.

When I run this code more that one time - I need updated only duplicates.

Now that code work fine, but when I run this code second time - this sql update me all records.

Hiw can I fix it?

Please help me.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add some simple data and the expected output ?

Comment: your secret_key value is different in main query and sub query. is it ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this query to update the second duplication record;

```
update platnosc w1 join ( select min(id) as w2_id, secret_key,date from platnosc group by secret_key,date ) w2 on w1.id > w2.w2_id and w1.secret_key = w2.secret_key  and w1.date = w2.date "set Configure your value and condition";
```

If you want to update all records then:

```
 update platnosc w1 join ( select min(id) as w2_id, secret_key,date from platnosc group by secret_key,date ) w2 on w1.id = w2.w2_id and w1.secret_key = w2.secret_key  and w1.date = w2.date "set Configure your value and condition";
```